# XCode gives a warning for iPad launch image in landscape

Tags: ipad, xcode4

my XCode 4 is giving me a warning about the launch image for iPad landscape mode, which does not fit 1024x748 size. I have checked the image and it is of this size, what is the problem ?

**UPDATE:** The issue is solved in iOS 5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have the same problem. I believe it is a bug.
Sent a bug report to apple. 
You are not alone.

**EDIT - the  new version released yesterday (7/6) fixed that problem**

Here is a screenshot from xcode -
[image]

No warnings

Comment: Well I think you are right, as long as nobody answers this question.

Comment: Just updated my xcode to the new version released yesterday and it seems they fixed that.

Comment: Thanks once again, I'll try that.

Comment: What version are you on? I'm running XCode 4.0.2 4A2002a which appears to be the latest version release version available through the portal.

Comment: I have the beta version that released  with iOS 5. it is Build 4C104.